# Pitch Black Image Editor & UV Editor

Tags: interface, uv-image-editor, versions

[image: Pitch Black Interface in Image Editor and UV Mapping]

Hi. I recently upgraded to Windows 10 and Blender 3.1.2
I noticed that I cannot see my selected faces in the Black UV Editing environment. Selection seems to be under the black pixel as if it is a mask. I tried updating my graphics card and other drivers and results seems to be the same. When I look at the previous version and other's interface, the UV Editor does not look like this. Is this a bug or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried File - Defaults - Load factory settings?

Comment: I have tried it. It did not change anything. I tried reinstalling and the problem is still there.
I've also checked the Video sequencer on Blender 3.2 its in the color Turquoise or blue green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer and might as well share it incase someone encounters a rare situations as mine.

Apparently its a hardware problem specifically with the graphics card. My outdated GPU only supports OpenGL 3.3 where the 2.93 and above requirements are OpenGL 4.3

I may be able to run Blender 3.2 and I'm lucky to see the some parts of the interface, but there were probably more errors that I was not able to encounter since I could not get the basics working. The solution given to me was to either upgrade Graphics card that supports the latest version of OpenGL or downgrade blender version that supports the current GPU.